# smtp works on cli, but not in php script

Tags: php, email, postfix-mta, msmtp

I have correctly set the postfix server according to [PHP+Ubuntu Send email using gmail form localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969783/phpubuntu-send-email-using-gmail-form-localhost/45125490#45125490), so that this msmtp sends the email via:

```
$ echo -e "Subject: Test Mail\r\n\r\nThis is my first test email." |msmtp --debug --from=default -t skrifix@seznam.cz
```

*/etc/msmtprc*

```
account default
host smtp.gmail.com
port 587
auth on
user autak987@gmail.com
password *********
from autak987@gmail.com
logfile /var/log/msmtp.log
```

`$ls -l /etc/msmtprc

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data 377 Aug 30 12:54 /etc/msmtprc
```

which works correctly (the defaul account is set in `/etc/msmtprc`. Then I have set the `sendmail_path` in `/etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini`:

```
sendmail_path = /usr/bin/msmtp -t
```

So I tried to execute an example from [php manual - mail](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) :

```
<?php
$to = 'skrifix@seznam.cz';
$sub = 'the subject';
$mes = 'hello';
$header = 'From: autak987@gmail.com\r\n'; //not even needed - the default account is set

mail($to, $sub, $mes, $header);
```

But I can't find the email in the address `skrifix@seznam.cz`. What I did wrong? it should be set according to that answer.

Edit:
tried to trigger the execution with root according to this [Sending mail through terminal using msmtp works fine, but doesn't work with php mail()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134184/sending-mail-through-terminal-using-msmtp-works-fine-but-doesnt-work-with-php), yet no success.

Edit2:
It got even more stranger. From 15 test sending (15*execution of php script), 2 mails really arived. But they were from "unknown-sender", where the sender should be default account specified in `/etc/msmtprc` and even specified in the php in header `From:...`. I am really confused, what is going on here.

Comment: you are sending email in VPS or shared hosting? Some hosting providers intentionally block usage of the mail() function for security

Comment: Using apache on debian machine and sending from localhost (that's why I tried to configure it according to the first link)

Comment: 1) Gmail requires TLS. Add `tls on` to `/etc/msmtprc`. 2) Your first example will not work. The command line option `--from=default` sets the from address to `default` and does not select the profile `default`. Use the option `--account=default`. 3) Review the PHP log files for error messages from the `send()` call. 4) You need to figure out if Gmail is accepting your emails (review the logs) or rejecting them.